# Ant: how do I pass values to properties from top level build.xml to build.xml in sub folders

Tags: ant

I have a set of folders with build.xml and sql scripts (one folder per database schema). I have a build.xml at the root level. I want to set the values of server, port, userid, password etc... in the root level build.xml and pass it to the build.xml in each of the folders. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

This way:

```
<ant antfile="sub/build.xml" inheritall="true"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more fine-grained control you can set `inheritall` to false and pass individual properties as nested elements of `<ant>` task.

E.g.

```
<ant antfile="sub/build.xml" inheritall="false">
  <property name="server" value="server.foo.bar"/>
  <property name="port" value="1234"/>
  ...
</ant>
```

Also, `<ant>` task accepts `<propertyset>` nested element, so you can bundle several properties together and just pass a single property set.

Answer (score 3):

The [`<ant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task does what you need:

> Runs Ant on a supplied buildfile. This
>   can be used to build subprojects.
>
> **By default, all of the properties of the current project will be available
>   in the new project.**

So you just need to invoke `<ant antfile="dir/build.xml"/>`. No need to set the `inheritAll` attribute, it defaults to `true`.